# Python, How to fill multiple curves that do not share abscissa coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, area, roc, auc

I am trying to fill the area between the top contour and the bottom contour of 4 curves, and the final aim is to compute the area of this filled region. The problem is that the curves do not share x-coordinates and so the use of `fill_between()` is not straightforward.

this is a starting point:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import auc
import json
import numpy as np

x1 = [0,   0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.75, 1]
y1 = [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 1,   1,    1]

x2 = [0,   0.01, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.75,  1]
y2 = [0.6, 0.5,  0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 1,     1]

x3 = [0,   0.2, 0.45, 0.5,  0.6, 0.9, 1]
y3 = [0.4, 0.5, 0.55, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 1]

plt.xlim([-0.01, 1.01])
plt.ylim([-0.01, 1.01])

auc1 = auc(x1, y1)
plt.plot(x1,y1 ,'r', label='(AUC = %.2f)' % auc1)

auc2 = auc(x2, y2)
plt.plot(x2,y2, 'b', label='(AUC = %.2f)' % auc2)

auc3 = auc(x3, y3)
plt.plot(x3,y3, 'g', label='(AUC = %.2f)' % auc3)

plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

and this is how they look like when plotted:

[image]

I would use another programming language if required. I can add more details if knowing exactly what I want to achieve would make the question easier to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to interpolate the yvalues on a new x array that contains all of the x values from all arrays. To do that you can use `numpy.interp`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = [0,   0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.75, 1]
y1 = [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 1,   1,    1]

x2 = [0,   0.01, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.75,  1]
y2 = [0.6, 0.5,  0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 1,     1]

x3 = [0,   0.2, 0.45, 0.5,  0.6, 0.9, 1]
y3 = [0.4, 0.5, 0.55, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 1]

# create array of all unique x values
x_all = x1 + x2 + x3
x_all = np.unique(np.array(x_all))

# interpolate y values on new xarray
y_all = np.empty((len(x_all), 3))
for i,x,y in zip(range(3), [x1,x2,x3], [y1,y2,y3]):
    y_all[:,i] = np.interp(x_all, x, y)

# find out min and max values    
ymin = y_all.min(axis=1)
ymax = y_all.max(axis=1)


plt.fill_between(x_all, ymin, ymax, alpha=0.6)

plt.plot(x1,y1 ,'r', label='(AUC = %.2f)')
plt.plot(x2,y2, 'b', label='(AUC = %.2f)')
plt.plot(x3,y3, 'g', label='(AUC = %.2f)')
plt.ylim(0,1.1)
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Of course you could also interpolate on a more dense grid,

```
x_all = np.linspace(0,1,101)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest your code works really well on that Xs and Ys. I tried with my real dataset and it does not fill between the curves. I think there is a floating point problem. Is there a way I can send you my real X1,Y1, X2,Y2 so that you could look at it? please